# Why didn't the Seons change?

Tags: cosmere, elantris

In the book Elantris, the Reod was caused by a giant earthquake opening a chasm which changed the shape of all the Aons. The Seons, which are basically living Aons, were presumably unchanged, since nobody noticed the change, which should have been obvious on the simpler Aons.

Comment: This seems like essentially the same question as your other one. Perhaps you could combine them?

Comment: What makes you think the Seons, which we've seen coming from plenty of places, are based on Elantris' rune?

Comment: elantris didnt break. arelon had an earthquake which opened a massive chasm, and since all aons' starting point is based on the significant geography of arelon (the coastline in the north, the mountain range in the east, the lake in the center and now the chasm in the south) the aons changed when the chasm opened, causing all existing aons, and by extension elantris, to be missing a line

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, they [did change](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/105-17th-shard-forum-qa/#e1267):

> **Master_Moridin**: Why aren't seons affected by the lack of a chasm line
>   in their Aon?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**: If they tried to actualize their Aon, it would have
>   an undesirable result. In addition, the chasm broke their bond to the
>   humans they were tied to, and you can see the result of that. So they
>   were affected.

We saw that Seons associated with Elantrians were exhibited some unusual behaviors, and indeed might have been considered to have lost their sentience. In fact, I'm fairly sure that their Aons did look different under close inspection, if the Seon was bonded to someone who'd be taken by the Shaod.

As to why they did, it wasn't because of the direct effect of the Reod, but because of their [Connection to people who were affected by it](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/239-alloy-of-law-release-party/#e10049):

> **Questioner (paraphrased)**:  Why do Seons become broken when their person is taken by the Shaod?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson (paraphrased)**:  A Seon has a Spiritual Connection with their user. When the Shaod takes the user, it messes
>   up the spiritual nature of the user, and it really messes up the
>   nature of the Seon.

Although the characters in the book aren't sure, it seems likely that the Seons predate Elantris, being Splinters of Devotion. As such, they're not going to be dependent on Elantris for their very existence, and the worst effects will come from their Connection to those affected by the Reod.